# PyGTK app is not quitting properly

Tags: python, pygtk, pygame

I wrote a little PyGTK app: [Workcycler](http://github.com/daddz/workcycler)

Now I have the problem that I need to hit the quit button twice for it to quit and I don't know why.
I´ve tested it extensively and it allways calls all quit functions but the program simply doesn't close after the first time.

It's a pretty short script so could someone please have a look over it?

I think the problem may come from using python's timers or a part from the pygame lib (mixer).

These are the important files I think: [workcycle.py](http://github.com/daddz/workcycler/blob/master/workcycle/workcycle.py) and [tray.py](http://github.com/daddz/workcycler/blob/master/workcycle/ui/tray.py)

Comment: Not shure - but if the problerm has to do with pygame be running, you could try adding a call to pygame.mixer.quit() just before calling gtk.main_quit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the `workcycle.ui.tray.WorkcycleTray.start` method twice (so `gtk.main` run twice )
once in the `workcycler` and another in  `workcycle.py` line 20, comment that line and everything works fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I´ve totally overseen that.